# how to post "Date" with POSTMAN JSON?

Tags: java, ajax, postman

Hello StackOverflow communitee, i'm trying to test my Ajax post request to set budgets with a starting date and an end date.

Im able to set all the other values but unfortunately my dates are not pushed... Does anyone have an idea ?

Im gonna put my JS AJAX request TEST, my postman and my JAVA Budget Class.

Thanks again F.

```java
package com.eBudget.eBudget;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;

import org.hibernate.mapping.ForeignKey;

import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Budget {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Integer idBudget;
    public String nom;
    public LocalDate datedeDebut;
    public Float valeur;
    public boolean etat;
    public Date datedeFin;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "budgets")
    public List<Users> users;

    public Budget(Integer idBudget, String nom, LocalDate datedeDebut,
                  Float valeur, boolean etat, Date datedeFin, List<Users> users) {
        this.idBudget = idBudget;
        this.nom = nom;
        this.datedeDebut = datedeDebut;
        this.valeur = valeur;
        this.etat = etat;
        this.datedeFin = datedeFin;
        this.users = users;
    }

    public Budget() {

    }

    public Integer getIdBudget() {
        return idBudget;
    }

    public void setIdBudget(Integer idBudget) {
        this.idBudget = idBudget;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public LocalDate getDatedeDebut() {
        return datedeDebut;
    }

    public void setDatedeDebut(LocalDate datedeDebut) {
        this.datedeDebut = datedeDebut;
    }

    public Float getValeur() {
        return valeur;
    }

    public void setValeur(Float valeur) {
        this.valeur = valeur;
    }

    public boolean isEtat() {
        return etat;
    }

    public void setEtat(boolean etat) {
        this.etat = etat;
    }

    public Date getDatedeFin() {
        return datedeFin;
    }

    public void setDatedeFin(Date datedeFin) {
        this.datedeFin = datedeFin;
    }

    public List<Users> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<Users> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

Postman Post Request

```json
{ 
    "id":4,
    "nom":"Course3",
    "dateDebut":"2019-12-12",
    "valeur":200,
    "etat":true,
    "dateFin":"2020-01-01"
}
```

Ajax request

```js
<script>
$("#formulaire").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // 1ère etape test en dur //
    console.log("#valideBudget");
    var nom = "Course";
    var dateDebut = 2019 - 12 - 12;
    var valeur = 200;
    var etat = true;
    var dateFin = 2020 - 01 - 01;
    // faire un json//
    //2 creer un objet test//
    var budget = {};
    budget.id = 4;
    budget.nom = nom;
    budget.dateDebut = dateDebut;
    budget.valeur = valeur;
    budget.etat = etat;
    budget.dateFin = dateFin;
    console.log(budget);
    console.log("tg");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(budget));
    // test//

    //3 requete ajax//

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        // objet que je lui envoie //
        data: JSON.stringify(budget),
        contentType: "application/json; charset= utf-8",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/budget"
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log("envoi effectuer");
    });
});
</script>
```

Result STATUS OK 200 on POSTMAN

```
{
    "idBudget": 12,
    "nom": "Course3",
    "datedeDebut": null,
    "valeur": 200.0,
    "etat": true,
    "datedeFin": null,
    "users": null
}
```

Comment: Why are you mixing `LocalDate` for debut but `Date` for fin? Do you understand the first is from the modern *java.time* classes that years ago supplanted the terrible legacy date classes such as `Date`? Furthermore, are you aware there is a `java.util.Date` *and* a `java.sql.Date`? You do not indicate which is in play here.

Comment: Well to be honest with im not aware about the difference between all the import you mentionned ? i supposed their is one connect to mysql worbench and an other one from java library.  BtW i set my date like this because i'm not sure that i can edit end date with LocalDate import.  Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: Search for *java.time* to learn more. (Covered many hundreds of time on Stack Overflow.) Never use date-time classes outside the `java.time` package, as they are terribly flawed and became legacy years ago with the adoption of JSR 310. For a date-only value, without time-of-day, and without time zone, use `java.time.LocalDate`.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the date variable in quotes?

```
var dateDebut = "2019-12-12";
```

and

```
var dateFin="2020-01-01";
```

Does that work for you?

-----------------**UPDATE**-----------------

If that didn't work, try using javascript date objects instead;

```
var dateDebut = new Date(2019,11,12,0,0,0,0);
```

and

```
var dateFin = new Date(2020,0,1,0,0,0,0);
```

Comment: Yep ofc @shivan Puri, i tried without quotes, simple, slash everything ...